# awk from file using echo and output to file

Tags: bash, awk

A.txt contains:

```
/*333*/
asdfasdfadfg
sadfasdfasgadas
@@@
/*555*/
hfawehfihohawe
aweihfiwahif
aiwehfwwh
@@@
/*777*/
jawejfiawjia
ajwiejfjeiie
eiuehhawefjj
@@@
```

B.txt contains:

```
555
777
```

I want to create the loop, for each string found in B.txt, then output the '/*'[the string] until right before the first '@@@' met to each own file (the string name is also used as file name).
So based on the sample above, the result should be :

555.txt, which contains:

```
/*555*/
hfawehfihohawe
aweihfiwahif
aiwehfwwh
```

and 777.txt, which contains:

```
/*777*/
jawejfiawjia
ajwiejfjeiie
eiuehhawefjj
```

I tried this script but it outputs nothing:

```
for i in `cat B.txt`; do echo $i | awk '/{print "/*"$1}/{flag=1} /@@@/{flag=0} flag' A.txt > $i.txt; done
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: The pattern `/{print "/*"$1}` selects every line which contains the string _{print "/*"_, followed by the content of the first field of the line. This does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a few alterations to your code provides the desired outcome with the example data provided:

```
while read -r f
do
    awk -v var="/[*]$f[*]/" '$0 ~ var {flag=1} /@@@/{flag=0} flag' A.txt > "$f".txt
done < B.txt

cat 555.txt
/*555*/
hfawehfihohawe
aweihfiwahif
aiwehfwwh

cat 777.txt
jawejfiawjia
ajwiejfjeiie
eiuehhawefjj
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Perhaps `awk -v var="/[*]$f[*]/ ....`  would be more accurate, though the difference does not matter for the sample data posted here.

Comment: Yes, great point @user1934428 - that would be better - I'll edit my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk` should work in any `awk`.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  if($0~/^\/\*/){
    line=$0
    gsub(/^\/\*|\*\/$/,"",line)
    arr[++count]=$0
    arr1[line]=count
    next
  }
  arr[count]=(arr[count]?arr[count] ORS:"") $0
  next
}
($0 in arr1){
  outputFile=$0".txt"
  print arr[arr1[$0]] >> (outputFile)
  close(outputFile)
}
' file1 file2
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                   ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                                ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when file1 is being read.
  if($0~/^\/\*/){                       ##Checking condition if current line starts with /* then do following.
    line=$0                             ##Setting $0 to line variable here.
    gsub(/^\/\*|\*\/$/,"",line)         ##using gsub to globally substitute starting /* and ending */ with NULL in line here.
    arr[++count]=$0                     ##Creating arr with index of ++count and value is $0.
    arr1[line]=count                    ##Creating arr1 with index of line and value of count.
    next                                ##next will skip all further statements from here.
  }
  arr[count]=(arr[count]?arr[count] ORS:"") $0  ##Creating arr with index of count and keep appending values of same count values with current line value.
  next                                  ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($0 in arr1){                           ##checking if current line is present in arr1 then do following.
  outputFile=$0".txt"                   ##Creating outputFile with current line .txt value here.
  print arr[arr1[$0]] >> (outputFile)   ##Printing arr value with index of arr1[$0] to outputFile.
  close(outputFile)                     ##Closing outputFile in backend to avoid too many opened files error.
}
' file1 file2                           ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `awk` solution for this:

```sh
awk '
FNR == NR {
   map["/*" $0 "*/"] = $0
   next
}
$0 in map {
   fn = map[$0] ".txt"
}
/^@@@$/ {
   close(fn)
   fn = ""
}
fn {print > fn}' B.txt A.txt
```